# twython search api rate limit: Header information will not be updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twython

I want to handle the Search-API rate limit of 180 requests / 15 minutes. The first solution I came up with was to check the remaining requests in the header and wait 900 seconds. See the following snippet:

```
results = search_interface.cursor(search_interface.search, q=k, lang=lang, result_type=result_mode)

while True:
    try:
        tweet = next(results)
        if limit_reached(search_interface):
            sleep(900)

        self.writer(tweet)


def limit_reached(search_interface):
    remaining_rate = int(search_interface.get_lastfunction_header('X-Rate-Limit-Remaining'))
    return remaining_rate <= 2
```

But it seems, that the header information are not reseted to 180 after it reached the two remaining requests.

The second solution I came up with was to handle the twython exception for rate limitation and wait the remaining amount of time:

```
results = search_interface.cursor(search_interface.search, q=k, lang=lang, result_type=result_mode)
while True:
    try:
        tweet = next(results)

        self.writer(tweet)
    except TwythonError as inst:
        logger.error(inst.msg)
        wait_for_reset(search_interface)
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        break


def wait_for_reset(search_interface):
      reset_timestamp = int(search_interface.get_lastfunction_header('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
      now_timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
      seconds_offset = 10

      t = reset_timestamp - now_timestamp + seconds_offset
      logger.info('Waiting {0} seconds for Twitter rate limit reset.'.format(t))
      sleep(t)
```

But with this solution I receive this message INFO: Resetting dropped connection: api.twitter.com" and the loop will not continue with the last element of the generator. Have somebody faced the same problems?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

just rate limit yourself is my suggestion (assuming you are constantly hitting the limit ...)

```
QUERY_PER_SEC = 15*60/180.0  #180 per 15 minutes
#~5 seconds per query
class TwitterBot:
    last_update=0
    def doQuery(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tdiff = time.time()-self.last_update
        if tdiff < QUERY_PER_SEC:
            time.sleep(QUERY_PER_SEC-tdiff) 
        self.last_update = time.time()
        return search_interface.cursor(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: I already thought about that. Am I right that with this solution I receive every 5 seconds a new twitter message? That would mean, that for one day I can obtain 24*60*60 / 5 = 17280 Tweets. Thats not very much! You're also right that this approach is not optimal for keywords that are not hitting the limit :/

Comment: yeah this was more of the easiest answer... more complicated would be to maintain your own sliding window of queries in last 15 minutes and when you get to 179 wait or something ...   yeah since I dont know your domain you are probably right ... 17k tweets a day seems like alot for most aplications I might use this for

Comment: This is what I did in the snippets above. The function limit_reached indicated if I hit the limit with some space remaining. This works well. But after the sleep method the remaining requests are still not reseted. Found the count parameter in the interface: "The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100.". With this it would possible to retrieve 100 tweets per 5 seconds.